# What causes a 13 volt drop from 24v (read) red wire connection to from air handler to thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

A voltage drop of 13 volts on the red thermostat "24v" wire. It reads 28v at air handler and 15v at the other, unconnected end. I was thinking a resisted short so I re-wired to an unused wire, same result.

I believe it is 18 gauge wire over a 25 foot run. Can any one explain the voltage drop the same constant voltage drop over the two different wires?

Comment: what is the transformer size (Watt)

Comment: Your Voltage to drop should not be more than 10% at 1 Amp load, so you have a wire/insulation problem somewhere along the run, or bad transformer

Answer (score 1):

Nothing causes a voltage drop in a wire that is not passing current.

There is something not-wire in there somewhere.

Comment: That's a good point.  OP said "unconnected", which means no current draw by the tstat.  So there has to be something loading down those wires or a voltage divider of some sort someplace along the route.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're right you replace the wires and still have large voltage drop.

That would indicate something is wrong with the transformer.

Find or get 24 V lamp and connect to the transformer to see if it can handle the load